# How to store selected date from jquery datepicker in a variable using c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I have a jquery calender on my aspx page as

```
<div id="selectDate"></div>
```

and following is the JS:

```
var array = ["23/08/2013", "24/08/2013", "25/08/2013"];
    $("#selectDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
        $('#selectDate').submit();},
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+1y +0m -1d',
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
        }
    });
```

Now, i need to store the selected date from the datepicker into the variable on .cs page,I know i have to use onSelect function, but I don't know how to do it, any help will be appreciated.

I am using Asp.net and C#.

Comment: Well, that is only possible doing some postback at that moment. You may need to configure your date webcontrol to post as soon as it change values...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date, put it in a asp.net hidden field using js and then when you post it back you can put it in a C# variable, something like this:

Add hidden field to your markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField Id="myDate" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Get the date and set it to the hiddenfield before postback:

```
var currentDate = $( "#selectDate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
$('#<% myDate.ClientID %'>).val(currentDate);
```

And when you post it you can use this in your code behind:

```
var selectedDate = DateTime.Parse(myDate.Value);
```

Comment: You'll want a `#` in front of that `ClientID` call (outside the server block).

Comment: @VahidND my aspx editor doesn't seem to detect `<asp:HiddenField`. Do I have to add any references/.dlls? Also do you have [any idea about my approach on this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24571944/1389394)

Comment: @bonCodigo `asp:HiddenField` as any other controls is defined in system.web assembly which is referenced by default, if you don't get intellisense for that, it might be caused by a syntax error somewhere in your aspx markup.