# Replacing Calendar control (its events) in asp.net with jQuery calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

Earlier Title: How to add a weekly view Calendar stripe in Web Page?

**Gridview**'s data is searched and displayed by **week of the year**. The weekly view calendar control should look like somewhat the picture shown below. The current month, week and date are highlighted.

Adding a calendar control and calculating the week of the year based on the date user clicked within C# is not an issue. But I need to format calendar control in a such way to highlight current week of the year and provides navigation to next and previous weeks of the year (consecutive).

In ASP.Net page, how can I achieve this?

[image]

### **EDIT** [17/07/2014]

After getting some rookie touch on Asp.Net and vee bit of understanding of jQuery, I realized this can be easily achieved via `jQuery DatePicker` in its UI. However I have couple of questions that need to be addressed while **migrating default asp.net Calendar control based code to use jQuery DatePicker**.

1. Is jQuery DatePicker also called as jQuery Calendar?
2. Can the following events be achieved in jQuery DatePicker?

   ```
      //event                      
      protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           ShowData("a");            
      }

      //method is used with page load event to get the data for current week (default)
      Calendar1.SelectedDate

   //event - user can only select a particular week, not the single date
   protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
   }
   ```
3. [Is it possible to get the selected week/date of the jQuery DatePicker into a variable? **YES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425831/how-to-store-selected-date-from-jquery-datepicker-in-a-variable-using-c)
4. Will it be an issue changing into jQuery instead of using built in calendar control for application's maintenance purpose.